# Cleanup failed - Can't Stat. (System cannot find the file specified) (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

All of a sudden my TortoiseSVN has stopped working - when I attempt an SVN Update I am getting the following message:

```
Error  Previous operation has not finished; run cleanup if it was interrupted
Error  Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.
```

When I run the SVN Cleanup as instructed using TortoiseSVN I then get the following error:

```
Cleanup failed to process the following paths
C:\Users\Me\SourceTree\server2\www.site.co.uk
Can't stat

'C:\Users\Me\SourceTree\server2\www.site.co.uk\public_html\assets\ckfinder\lang\de.js'
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have no ideas what has happened - the ckfinder directory is **never used** & hasn't been touched & I cannot understand why the error would even relate to that directory anyway.

I've tried re-creating this by renaming the existing folder & attempting to do a 'checkout' of the site again to my local PC - but the process stops after a few minutes of downloading files and gives me the **Cannot find the file specified** error again.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this as i'm really baffled?
I'm using Windows 7
TortoiseSVN 1.7.6, Build 22632 - 64 Bit , 2012/03/08 18:29:39
Subversion 1.7.4, 
apr 1.4.5
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012
zlib 1.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd... Avast was flagging this file as virus and causing the problem???! Once I disabled it everything worked. Avast seems to have an issue with false flagging safe files